# retrieving similar column of 2 joined tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to get all the **mutual friends** of the 2 users (dummy4, and dummy 5)
then  retrieve all of their fname, lname and profile picture.

user_info

```
id    fname      lname     profile_pic

1     barrack    obama     1.jpg
2     tom        jones     2.jpg
3     dummy1     dummy1    3.jpg
4     dummy2     dummy2    4.jpg
5     dummy3     dummy3    5.jpg
6     dummy4     dummy4    6.jpg
```

friend

```
counter     user_id        friend_id      request_status
1           2              1              friend
2           4              5              friend
3           3              4              friend
4           5              3              friend
5           1              6              waiting
6           6              3              friend
7           1              3              friend
8           2              6              waiting
9           1              4              friend
10          3              2              friend
11          5              1              canceled
12          4              6              friend
```

here is the query that I've tried

```
SELECT profile_pic, fname, lname FROM 
user_info JOIN friend ON 
(friend.friend_id = user_info.id OR friend.user_id = user_info.id) AND
((friend.user_id = 3 OR friend.friend_id = 4) AND 
(friend.user_id = 4 OR friend.friend_id = 3))
AND friend.request = 'friend' GROUP BY user_info.id
```

but it returns nothing.

I want to make the result to be something like this

```
id              fname             lname              profile_pic
1               barrack           obama              1.jpg
5               dummy1            dummy1             5.jpg
6               dummy4            dummy4             6.jpg
```

Comment: u have no dummy5. correct your datasets, query u tried and expected result

Comment: you have too many arguments in your join condition. Most of them should be in WHERE clause.

Comment: @JoshuaK - ok, wait.

Comment: first error: friend.request = 'friend'... you have no column "request" in friend table. pls give us real data no sciencefiction code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just using `exists`?

```
SELECT u.*
FROM user_info u
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM friend f
              WHERE u.id IN (f.user_id, f.friend_id) AND
                    $friend1 IN (f.user_id, f.friend_id) AND
                    f.request_status = 'friend'
             ) AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM friend f
              WHERE u.id IN (f.user_id, f.friend_id) AND
                    $friend2 IN (f.user_id, f.friend_id) AND
                    f.request_status = 'friend'
             ) AND
      u.id NOT IN ($friend1, $friend2);
```

I'm not sure how you are representing the friends.  There is nothing called "dummy5" in your sample data, so they are just represented by variables in the above code.

Comment: please don't do this. using a column from the outside-query in a subquery means, that the subquery have to be calculate n times, where n is the count of rows in user_info.

Comment: @JoshuaK . . . This is called a *correlated subquery*.  It is often a very reasonable  way of writing queries.  As with most SQL constructs (and most constructs in most languages), there are cases were it might not be appropriate.  That does not justify a warning against its use.

Comment: The official mysql manual warns itself: `Otherwise, they are inefficient and likely to be slow. Rewriting the query as a join might improve performance. ` source: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/correlated-subqueries.html. And if you don't check if it can optimized your query...

Comment: @GordonLinoff I checked it. Take both in a fiddle and checked the execution plan: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aa827/26/0 There you can see: your query uses DEPENDENT SUBQUERY. Read online about it if you don't know what it ment to the optimizer. It's better to use MATERIALIZED subquerys (checkout the lower execution plan if you are interested). And some lecture about subquery optimization and DEPENDENT SUBQUERY vs MATERIALIZED subquerys: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/subquery-optimization.html

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT profile_pic, fname, lname
FROM user_info u
WHERE u.`id` IN(
   SELECT DISTINCT IF(f1.`user_id`=4,f1.`friend_id`,f1.`user_id`) as mutfri
   FROM friend as f1
   WHERE IF(f1.`user_id`=4,f1.`friend_id`,f1.`user_id`) IN(
      SELECT IF(f2.`user_id`=3, f2.`friend_id`, f2.`user_id`) as friend_id
      FROM friend as f2
      WHERE f2.`request_status` = 'friend' AND (f2.`user_id` = 3 OR f2.`friend_id` = 3)
   ) AND f1.`request_status`='friend' AND (f1.`user_id` = 4 OR f1.`friend_id` = 4)
);
```

this is a solution without using columns from the outside query inside the subquery (synchronized subquerys). So it has a better performance on greater databases.